# Detect unselected Item in GridView - Multiselect

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-8.1

In my Windows 8 application I am using GridView with Multiselect enabled , now what I need is to get the item which I deselect, I tried selection events but no success , anyone please guide me what is the right way to do it?

Comment: Is it WPF or Windows Form ?

Comment: It is windows 8.1 application.

Comment: To determine which cells, rows, or columns are selected in the DataGridView control, you can access the SelectedCells, SelectedRows, or SelectedColumns property.

Comment: you could do the following: on `SelectionChanged` event save the selected indices and compare the new and old selected indices. if an old index is not part of the new indices then its the unselected index.

Comment: Follow this link...It should help. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx  As Koryu pointed out, you can track all the rows selected inside the event  DataGridView1.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(
            DataGridView1_SelectionChanged);

Comment: Koryu , It can be one solution but I am wondering if there is any direct or more quick way to know the last deselected item from gridview?(my gridview is having multiselect enable)